# Исправить ошибку TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, sqlite3

```
import sqlite3 as sq

with sq.connect('mydb.sqlite3') as con:
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM one_product")
    Products = cur.fetchall
    print(Products)

Products_stroka = [str(i) for i in Products]
```

Мне необходимо получить список `Products` из базы данных, а далее сделать из него список со строковым типом данных.

В итоге выдало ошибку

> TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

к последней строке. 
Помогите с решением пожалуйста

Comment: Не хватает скобок. Где именно не хватает - пусть будет домашним заданием.

Comment: Сразу увидел, спасибо!